Function overloading between suspend and non-suspend function is not possible in Kotlin
I want to provide synchronous version of my asynchronous function, but I can't over load, the function have structure like this. Who can explain, why I can't, and is there any other way to overload function for my case.
suspend fun foo(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
    delay(100)
    return a + b
}

fun foo(a: Int, b: Int): Result<Int> {
    //delay
    return Result.success( a + b)
}


How would we know which function we call with foo(4, 5)? We can't have two almost identical functions, no matter suspend or not, you need to rename one of them. Also, it sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need to do this?

Please [edit] your question and explain why you need the two functions to have the same name and parameters. Changing either would solve the problem, why isn't that a solution for you?

@broot It's easy to tell which of those two functions you need to call if you can unambiguously determine the return type from the calling context. Some languages (e.g. Swift) will allow overloads that differ only in return type. In Swift I can write let x: Int = foo(4, 5) or let y: Result<Int> = foo(4, 5) and the compiler will insert the correct overload.

And Kotlin doesn't do this. Overloads are identified by name+params types. Return type is not used for overloading. Even if technically speaking it is a part of the function signature, at least in JVM and JVM can use such overloads without problems.

In the java when we want to overload the function we have to change it's signature. Which is function name or parameter. When we define suspend in kotlin we just identify of the environment of function where it can be run like coroutine. You can check this link for information: java signature
To give example you can change like that:
fun foo(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
    return a + b
}
suspend fun foo(a: Int, b: Int, isSuspend: boolean): Result<Int> {
    if(isSuspend) {
        delay(100)
        return Result.success( a + b)
    }else {
        return Result.failure("Call suspend")
    }
}


Is using completion block here good practice as well, or not?
